# DynamoDB : Filter expression for collection nested objects

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Given the data structure below, I would like to write a filter expression to query all items that match the given expression (items.name = :param)

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    // nested collection
    "nestedValues": [
         {
             "id" : "1",
             "name":"item1" 
         },
         {
             "id": "2",
             "name":"item2" 
         }
    ]
}
```

I simply tried (but it doesn't work):

```
String filterExpression = "nestedValues.name = :param";
Map valueMap = new HashMap();
valueMap.put(":param", "item2");
ItemCollection itemCollection = table.scan(
       new ScanSpec()
       .withFilterExpression(filterExpression)
       .withValueMap(valueMap)
);
```

When I tried (Of course it work since I specified the index in collection) :

```
String filterExpression = "nestedValues[1].name = :param";
Map valueMap = new HashMap();
valueMap.put(":param", "item2");
ItemCollection itemCollection = table.scan(
        new ScanSpec()
        .withFilterExpression(filterExpression)
        .withValueMap(valueMap)
);
```

How can I easily get all database items which have an item with name "item2" in nestedValues collection ?

Thank you in advance

(I also asked on AWS forum here : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=881391&#881391)